# How to quit eclipse so that it allows me to delete .metadata .lock and .tresoslog file?

Tags: eclipse, locking

I want to delete .metadata file but it doesn't allow me because it says it is being locked by another process.But I badly want to delete .meatdata folder which is being generated by eclipse.It has .lock file and .log file and a plugins folder.Please suggest a way to delete this .metadata folder.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the entire folder? Explain what your problem/goal is, not just the "solution" you're trying.

Comment: Deleting the whole .metadata folder will effectively destroy the workspace. Tell us why you think you need to do this.

Comment: I have two batch scripts.One launches eclipse, another batch script tries to import projects into workspace. If i try to execute first batch script ,it creates a metadata file(here i am launching eclipse).If I try to execute the second batch script it shows error stating that i have to change my workspace because I already have a metadata file which was generated by my first batch script.This is the reason I want to delete my first metadata file before executing second one.

Answer (score 1):

- You should never delete the `.metadata` folder (unless you really
  want to throw away the workspace it's in).
- Deleting the `.lock` file is fine, assuming the `eclipse` process (and the `java` process that it launches) are not running. However, doing so is only necessary after a crash which is generally pretty rare (for example, I haven't had to do it in several years, using Eclipse daily).
- You can delete the log file(s) whenever you want.

Comment: If deleting .metadata is not possible.Can I replace one metadata with another metadata using python or batch command?

Comment: No, not really. That folder is internal data for an Eclipse workspace that isn't tolerant of arbitrary changes. As the comments have asked, update your question with the "why" of what you're asking.